# Heroku applications and building process

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have just one question:
Why when you push to heroku, it do same all tasks to execute app?

For example I just modified one file index.js, ok, I need to `git add index.js`, `git commit -am "Message"` and `heroku push origin master`, but when I'm pushing to heroku, it pushing one file but do a lot of unnecessary things like

1. Again installing Node
2. Again installing dependencies (node modules), there are the same but heroku again download all dependencies
3. Again build cache of node modules

Why Heroku can't analyze package.json and do not install again new modules? Why it installs again Node if in Procfile I have the same `web: npm run server`? These actions are eating a lot of time and resources, I'm don't understand that.

Comment: You use Git only to manage the software versioning and send new commits. Once you've sent the new commits to the hosting site, Heroku takes over from there: they look at the commits, decide whether they like them or not, and use Git's existing mechanisms to convey Heroku's opinion of your commits back to you. You can think of Git as a sort of bike-messenger at this point: it can't *change* the contracts it's messaging, it can only *convey* them.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a ci/cd pipeline and deploy directly from your github page